# Godaddy Server location?

Tags: web-hosting, server, godaddy

I recently changed my Godaddy shared hosting's location from US to a Europe based data center.

After the migration I looked up the new server's IP and it's based in the US too. ("Arizona - Scottsdale - Godaddy.com Llc")

Are Godaddy kidding me? Then what's the point to have a "Europe based" server?

The IP address in question is 160.153.128.13.

Comment: If you do a traceroute of the IP, where is it based then? It might just be that GoDaddy are listed as the _owners_ - depending on where you looked it up.

Comment: That is just the IP allocation. It is not the location.

Comment: 160.153.0.0/16 is indeed registered to GoDaddy through ARIN, but since it's a direct allocation that doesn't have to mean much. Whois only tells you part of the story; they could, in principle, be publishing routes causing a portion of that netblock to end up in non-ARIN space.

Comment: Yeah, I'm fully agree with @closetnoc. IP is just allocation, it can't describe location. If they hide their IP, you cant even ping it or know the location.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do a traceroute on the IP address in question and you will more than likely find that the IP address traces to Europe somewhere. The whois record for the IP address in question is simply returning the registered owner of the IP address range and their organisational details. It will show up as the US as that is where GoDaddy is registered and where they will have registered their IP address range but just because it is registered there does not mean that it is assigned to a US server.

As an example my company website is hosted by Amazon Web Services out of their Sydney data center, when I do a whois lookup on the EIP for my instance it returns as being registered in the US to Amazon Technologies. That doesn't mean my instance is in the US, it just means that my hosting provider's company is registered at that location (usually the head office address is used).

Comment: Traceroute showed me that the IP is in the US.

The weird thing is that the traceroute for the previous server tooked 9 hops, now with the new one it takes 22 hops!

Comment: I have checked the IP address you have provided and the registration information is attached to GoDaddies head office in the US and is attached to GoDaddies global network (AS26496). A check of PeeringDB confirms that they have multiple peering arrangements in Europe through the Amsterdam internet exchange (AMS-IX) as well as directly to two telecommunications providers in Amsterdam. From what I can see while the IP address is registered in the US it is attached to the server in Europe. If it is accessed from a US connection then it will be routed through their US peering point...

Comment: And if it is accessed through a European connection then it will be routed through their Amsterdam peering points. The thing to remember with IP routing is that it will access the IP owners network through the fastest and cheapest connections depending on routing configuration and the ISP the customer has. GoDaddy appears to block traceroute at their gateways so there is no way to trace past the point where your connection enters the GoDaddy network. If you are still concerned then contact GoDaddy support and ask them to confirm that the server is in fact in Europe.

Comment: In case you're interested you can see all known GoDaddy peering points at https://www.peeringdb.com/net/430

Comment: @PlanetScaleNetworks When I do a traceroute (from SE), there is a noticable jump in roundtrip times between hop 9 kbn-bb3-link.telia.net (62.115.139.60) (at <30 ms) and hop 10 nyk-bb1-link.telia.net (213.155.131.135) (at >110 ms), and the roundtrip times are holding solidly on both sides of that jump, which would seem to indicate a great geographical distance being covered between those two. To get 80 ms for a transatlantic hop EU-US the signal would travel at about 30% of light speed grand total, which isn't completely unreasonable. To the IP where I start getting timeouts is ~170 ms.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Well that would tend to confirm that the server is in fact located in Europe and that the gateway you are being blocked at is GoDaddies European gateway.

Comment: @PlanetScaleNetworks I'm not sure how that follows (170-180 ms from Sweden to anywhere in Europe seems excessive no matter how you slice it), but I'll leave it at that.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Sorry Michael, I was under the impression SE was based in the US, if you are located in Sweden and you have those high times then perhaps the server is in fact located in the US in which case the only option would be to speak to GoDaddy support and find out why a server which is meant to be in Europe is in the US. I am based in Australia so my traces tend to be the same whether a server is in Europe or in the US so I could only go on peering and BGP records for the IP.

Comment: @PlanetScaleNetworks You do realize that SE is the country code for Sweden, right?

Comment: I realise that now I thought for some stupid reason when you said SE you meant Stack Exchange

Answer (score -1):

GoDaddy's major infrastructure is focused on the Phoenix
region. Anyway it's just the IP allocation.
It doesn't mean your location.

Comment: Actually, this is about IP address allocation and not location. Because an IP address is allocated to a company in one location, does not mean that is where the IP address is used. In the OPs case, it very well could be used within a European NOC.